# Are there more perfect powers of this form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, perfect-powers

Let $a,b$ be integers , $a\ge 3$ , $b\ge 1$

> If $f_a$ is the $a$ th cyclotomic polynomial, are there any perfect powers of the form $f_a(b)$ apart from $121$ and $343$ ?

In the range $$3\le a\le 1\ 000\ ,\ 1\le b\le 1\ 000$$ there are no more perfect powers as this pari/gp program shows :

```
gp > for(a=3,1000,f=polcyclo(a);for(b=1,1000,s=subst(f,x,b);if(ispower(s)>0,print([a,b,factor(s)]))))
[3, 18, Mat([7, 3])]
[5, 3, Mat([11, 2])]
[6, 19, Mat([7, 3])]
gp >
```

Any idea or reference ? Is it known whether only the $3$ pairs give a perfect power ?

Update : I extended the range to $a,b\le 2\ 000$ without finding another pair.

Comment: [OEIS A208242](https://oeis.org/A208242) is related although not exactly what you are asking. It's the same I believe when $a$ is prime.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me, that for some primefactor $p$ to occur to a power larger than $1$ it must be that $a \le p-1$, so ususally at its ***first*** occurence (when we list factorizations of `polcyclo(a,b)` with fixed $b$ and increasing $a$). This reminds me of a proof of the LTE-lemma which I've done once, but this is at the moment only vague. The only exceptions I've seen so far are if $p=2$, but $p$'s powers occur as well early. So I'd look, whether by this hypothese the searchspace can  be reduced.

Comment: Ehmm, by the preceding comment I meant to collect information on cases, where powers are part of such `polcyclo()`at all - to get a feeling for this, but of course this is not specific enough to have the `polcyclo()` a perfect power at all. Just to make clear the intent of my comment 3 hours ago.